# Is [textarea] tag not too focused on HTML?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I think the SO [textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textarea) tag is too focused on the HTML markup language. As per the tag excerpt info:

> A textarea is an HTML element (tag) used to create a multi-line plain-text editing field.

However, when we look at the "related tags" section, there are 361 questions which are also [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)-tagged, and most of them are related to either the [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) or the [javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx) GUI libraries. As well, a few questions which are tagged [textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textarea) are tagged [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net).

**So, should we edit the [textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textarea) tag to talk about multi-line editing fields in general, and not about the HTML `<textarea>` element?**

Comment: That's only 6.5% of the questions, not a problem.  The primary tag breaks out the [java]-specific usage.